# Can I render a jinja2 template that is a blob/blobstore rather than a file in GAE/Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

++++ see solution at bottom (2nd update) ++++

I am a relative newbie to Google App Engine and Python.

I have a number of jinja2 templates (that were generated programatically) that are stored as blobs (because GAE does not allow the programs to write to files).  I now want to render these blob templates but I don't know how to refer to them in the render statement.

If need be, I might be able to store these templates in the blobstore.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  An example of what such a render statement would look like would be super.

(I have included Django in the tags because I suspect referencing a template for Django would probably be similar.)

Thanks for any assistance.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++ Modified question followup to trying to use variable as template source for jinja2 ++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
I am trying to get this to work with a TextProperty field and made a simple test (that assumes I already retrieved the text field) as follows:

```
FileTxt = '<html><body><br /><br /><p>The first test value starts here {{val1}}.  And {{val2}} is the 2nd test value.</p></body></html>'
val1 = 'H value 1 H'
val2 = 'H second value H'
self.render_template(FileTxt, {'val1': val1, 'val2': val2})
```

This returns an "Invalid filename" error.

I noticed it is trying to open file ...\templates\...

I suspect I have to modify the following somehow.

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_environment = \
    jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(TEMPLATE_DIR))
```

How would I modify this to make it work with a template in a variable instead of in a file?  Or what else would I have to do to make the file-less version work?

Thanks.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++ the following is working!  Thanks to both of you! ++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
class TextFileRender(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        val1 = 'H value 1 H'
        val2 = 'H second value H'
        env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FunctionLoader(loader))
        self.render_template(env.get_template('y'), {'val1': val1, 'val2': val2})
```

I then added the loader in a separate .py file (not sure why I always have to have functions that I want to call in a separate file and then add to import)

```
def loader(x):
    r = '<html><body><br /><br /><p>The first test value starts here {{val1}}.  And {{val2}} is the 2nd test value.</p></body></html>'
    return r
```

The above is working.  But now my problem is that the html content in one variable extends another html template (that is also stored in the datastore).  Can I make the extends statement in the html ({% extends "master_template.html" %}) somehow be something like {% extends nv.get_template('master_template') %}?

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You can store template data in either location (blobstore, datastore), and the solution is the same. The normal jinja2 loader is a `FileSystemLoader`. You should try something like the [FunctionLoader](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.FunctionLoader), and return values from fetched blobstore (or datastore) entries.

For example:

```
def loader(blob_key):
    r = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key)
    return r.read()

env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FunctionLoader(loader))

rendered_template = env.get_template('some blob key').render({'k': 'v'})
```

And you should of course use some kind of caching (local, memcache) instead of fetching from the blobstore each time.

Comment: I prefer to use the datastore (textproperty) for storing dynamic HTML files. And with the NDB datastore API you can use automatic caching.

Comment: I agree. I discussed the blobstore because of the question's note of it.

Comment: I am trying to make it work with a textproperty.  Please see the modified question.  I am getting an error because it is still looking for a file.  Thanks.

Comment: IT IS WORKING - Thank You both!  It took a little trial and error, but it is working.  See edited Question.  I now have a related problem of how to get the extends statement in the template text to also reference a database record.  Perhaps I should post this as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question about template inheritance. The answer is: when you implement a function loader it will be called  twice. First for the child and then for the base template.
For this you have to change your loader. Now it loads a fixed HTML string. Your parameter x contains the name of the template. Clear?
By the way: the function loader will also be called when you use jinja includes

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. But you can also store HTML templates with additional information in the datastore. I use content = db.TextProperty() to store this HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  That is great news!  How would you get the jinja2 template renderer to get its templates from either the return render statement to take the template either from the blobstore or the datastore (or the variable retrieved from the datastore)?  Thanks.

Comment: I do not know if I understand your question correct. 
But you can read the html template from the db and render the html template from a string. environment.from_string("""your template text here""") or create a function loader.